# Combining 1:M tables with removing duplicate fields

Tags: sql, database

Is it possible to display 2 column with no direct relationship side by side without a 'product' (column1xcolumn2)?

check this. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/212b6/1

I am trying create a query that displays all group_id,website and History with minimum duplicate fields. I have 3 tables- Group, Website and History but it displays cartesian join. If I have 4 websites and 3 History for 1 group. It displays 12 records. I want something lik this :

```
      group_id   |   website  |  History
          1         website1      hist1
          1         website2      hist2
          1         website3      hist3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in most databases by using `row_number()` to assign a row number.  This is ANSI standard functionality.  To come close to what you want:

```
select g.group_id, w.website, h.ma_history
from (select g.*, row_number() over (order by group_id) as seqnum
      from tbl_group g
     ) g full outer join
     (select w.*, row_number() over (order by website) as seqnum
      from table_website w
     ) w
     on g.seqnum = w.seqnum full outer join
     (select h.*, row_number() over (order by ma_history) as seqnum
      from table_ma_history h
     ) h
     on h.seqnum = coalesce(g.seqnum, w.seqnum)
```

The difference from your desired representation is that the "missing" values are not replicated from one row to the next.  Instead, they are represented as NULL.  For your example:

```
  group_id   |   website  |  History
      1         website1      hist1
      NULL      website2      hist2
      NULL      website3      hist3
```

Since you say "something like", is this sufficiently close?  Replicating the values is easier or harder depending on the database.